# PPO advantage estimate - Why does advantage estimate have $r_t+\gamma V(s_{t+1})-V(s_t)$

Tags: reinforcement-learning, papers, proximal-policy-optimization

So I've been looking at this formula for advantage estimate

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \hat{A}_t = \delta_t + (\gamma \lambda)\delta_{t+1} + ... +  (\gamma \lambda)^{T-t+1}\delta_{T-1}\\
&\text{where}\ \delta_t = r_t +\gamma V(s_{t+1}) - V(s_t)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $r_t$ is the reward at time $t$ and $V(s_t)$ is the estimated value of $s_t$ and $\gamma$ is future discount. Why is $\delta_t$ useful? As in why is it useful to calculate reward from time $t$ from the discounted estimated reward from that time onward of $s_t$ and subtract the value estimate of $s_t$

[Original PPO Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06347.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets notice, that $\hat{A}=\delta_t$ is a unbiased estimate of $A$ in a sense, that
$$
E_{s_{t+1}}[r_t + \gamma V(s_{t+1}) - V(s_t)] = E_{s_{t+1}}[Q(a_t, s_t) - V(s_t)] = A(a_t, s_t)
$$
Here we abuse the fact, that $V(s)$ is known, but in reality we know only its approximation, so the bias of estimator will be correlated to error of estimation of $V$ by  $V_\theta(s)$. By increasing the trajectory we can minimise the impact of $V_\theta(s_{t+1})$, lets write
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
&\hat{A}_t^{(1)}:=\delta^V_t& =r_t + \gamma V(s_{t+1}) - V(s_t) \\
&\hat{A}_t^{(2)}:=\delta^V_t + \gamma\delta^V_{t+1}&=r_t + \gamma r_t + \gamma^2V(s_{t+2}) - V(s_t)\\
&\hat{A}_t^{(3)}:=\delta^V_t + \gamma\delta^V_{t+1}+\gamma^2\delta^V_{t+2}&=r_t + \gamma r_t + \gamma^2r_{t+2}+\gamma^3V(s_{t+3}) - V(s_t)\\
&...&\\
&\hat{A}_t^{(\infty)} := \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \gamma^i\delta_{t+i}^{V}
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

The longer the traction, the smaller the term $\gamma^i$ at $V(s_{t+i})$, therefore the approximation of advantage function is less biased.

It is not perfect, since the variance is increasing with longer path, e.g. $\hat{A}^{(1)}_t$ has low variance and high bias, and $\hat{A}^{(\infty)}_t$ has low bias, but high variance. The tradeoff can be introduced by taking some $i < \infty$ and estimating the A by $\hat{A}^{(i)}_t$. But choice of $i$ is not evident. By analogy of generalisation for TD($\lambda$), described in [Sutton's book, chapter
12.8](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/10-703/textbook/BartoSutton.pdf) the other way to introduce the trade-off between bias and variance is to take a weighted sum. In practical case of course the infinite trajectories are not accessible. So the trajectories of length T are taken into account, which results exactly in
$$
\hat{A}_t = \sum_{i=0}^{T-(t+1)} (\gamma \lambda)^i \delta^{V_\theta}_{t + i}
$$
Where $\lambda$ introduces the trade off between bias and variance of advantage function estimation.

For further detailed reading I would highly recommend looking at the other [article by J. Schulman](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02438). It has a section (3. Advantage Function Estimation) on exactly this question.

Comment: Is there any reason, why you put the index for the advantage A on the top instead of replacing the step `t`?

Comment: Im not sure I understand exactly what do you mean. Are you referring to $\hat{A}^{(i)}_t$ notation? And the question is why I didn't write it as $\hat{A}_{(i)}$ ?

Comment: Sorry: yes exactly. Because otherwise, given a trajectory, I would need to calculate: $\hat{A}^{(1)}_{0}$, $\hat{A}^{(1)}_{1}$, $\hat{A}^{(2)}_{2}$ and so on... Then I need to repeat the same process again for $\hat{A}^{(2)}_{t}$. It shouldn't be: $\hat{A}_{0}$, $\hat{A}_{1}$, $\hat{A}_{2}$ ... instead?

Comment: I think I see where the misunderstanding is coming from! So each of $\hat{A}^{(j)}_i$ is an estimate of advantage function, so you would have to pick one to use in specific case. You would compute only $\hat{A}^{(1)}_t$ for example, for all the $t$ in the trajectory. However there is a bias-variance tradeoff - longer trace gives less bias, but high variance ( The estimate is accurate, but takes a lot of data to converge ) and shorter trace - gives low variance, but high bias ( It converges very fast, but is not very accurate ). So the question is - which length you should choose?

Comment: To answer this question $\hat{A}_t$ is proposed. If you look at the formula, it uses all the trajectory information ( like $\hat{A}^{(T)}_t$ ), so it supposed to have high variance and low bias. However, there is an extra parameter $\lambda$ that added to control that trade-off. Notice, that if $\lambda$ is very small, then $(\gamma \lambda)^i \delta^{V_\theta}_{t + i}$ becomes small very fast with increasing $i$ and the information from the end of the trajectory is not used! This all to say, that $\hat{A}_t$ is actually a different estimator from $\hat{A}_t^{(i)}$. Hope it helps!

Comment: If I understood right (I'm still not really sure), it is exactly the same as $TD(\lambda)$. It is correct? I mean, the same concept, not the same algorithm. That means, if $\lambda = 0$ is one case and if $\lambda = \infty$ then it is another case

Comment: It looks to me, that $\lambda \in [0, 1]$, so you can't have $\lambda = \infty$. Yes its the same as $\text{TD}(\lambda)$, but its $\hat{A}(\lambda)$ :) So for different $\lambda$ you will have different estimates of advantage function.

Comment: You are right: $\lambda \in [0, 1]$, I mistook meaning for $\lambda = 1$ you get the MC in $\infty$ case. Thank you very much for your patience and explanations!